# Concurrency issues with django on appengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, concurrency

Running a Django application on Appengine we need to make a query that returns approx. 450 rows per request including joins M2M prefetch_related and select_related.

When we make many concurrent requests, the query time for each request goes up in a way that all requests end simultaneously.

Running the same concurrent requests on a non-appengine Django installation or in an appengine instance that has threading set to false do not show this behavior.

There is also a slight improvement when the requests are separated to different appengine instances.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is this using Cloud SQL?  Are you seeing this on the dev_appserver or production?

Comment: This is using Cloud SQL on appengine (production). not on dev_appserver.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your database backend is too heavily loaded by your query.  Have you tried upgrading to a higher tier?

The basic tier only handles 25 concurrent queries.  You said "many" in your question, so if "many" > 25 that's the source of your problem:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/pricing

Comment: We tried upgrading for a bigger tier and it didn't help. We also ran the raw queries through the sql query tool making the same queries mutiple times simultaneously and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you run tests to show when this problem starts showing up?  ie how many concurrent queries do you need to start showing problems?